# How to pass an array in query parameter url react

Tags: reactjs

I Am using multiselect dropdown, what i want is whatever i've selected in dropdown to send it to the server by calling an api which contains query param to accomodate these dropdown result. I have made an array of selected items.

```
Array(3) [ "contact", "fee", "inbox" ]
```

I want this array to get pass to below url like this:

```
http://localhost.com/api/influencers?status=contact&status=fee&status=inbox
```

With my approach i am ending up with this:

```
http://localhost:8080/details?status[]=contact&status[]=fee&status[]=inbox
```

Can anyone please help me with it

```
const InfluencersList = props => {
    const [availability, setAvailability] = useState(null);

    const handleAvailabilityChange = value => {
        const availability1 = value;
        setAvailability(value);
        getFilterData(availability1, null);
    };

    const getFilterData = (search, pageNumber) => {
        let params = {};
        params.status = search; //search is array [contact,

        if (pageNumber) {
            params.page = pageNumber; // no is array is number 
        }
        axios.get("/api/influencers", { params: params }).then(res => {
            setState({
                items: res.data.data
            });
        });
    };

    <ChoiceList
        title="Availability"
        titleHidden
        choices={statuses}
        selected={availability || []}
        onChange={handleAvailabilityChange}
        allowMultiple
    />
}
```

Comment: You said dropdown[] is coming twice, but I don't see it. Did you post the full text? From what you said, it is the right way and outcome.

Comment: dropdown[] is coming twice I have corrected it . My question now is:  How to pass to the following URL like this: http://localhost.com/api/influencers?status=contact&status=fee&status=inbox.  waiting for your reply.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to build your `params` with multiple query with same name.

Iterate over `search` and for each value you [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) to your params a new status value:

```
const getFilterData = (search, pageNumber) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    search.forEach(value => params.append('status', value));

    if (pageNumber) {
        params.append('page', pageNumber) ;
    }
    axios.get("/api/influencers", { params }).then(res => {
        setState({
            items: res.data.data
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , This is possible, but the PageNumber is invalid because it's not an array

Answer (score 0):

Why not -with axios- you send a string as:

"contact;fee;inbox"

and in the backend convert this string to an array using a function like split(';')?

Comment: What is your back end reading? What language are you using in your back end? Axios  and java script/react are typically for the front end unless you use nodejs as web server where you can use java script for back end coding.

Comment: Back-end encoding.  I use laravel is php

Comment: and, after the axios request is sent from the front end, what is receiving the respective controller function? I had a similar problem and the controllers were always able to get the string after processing a json object that contained the string. The use of json is kind of standard in these cases.